# MySQL Database compare 2 Rows

Tags: mysql, function

I have a database for a Open Source Point of Sale System. 
A table named ticketlines contains every sold item.
Any discount given is stored in this table without an item name.
I'm trying to find a query where I can read out the line with the NULL product name with the line before to calculate the items sell price.

[POS Table Ticketlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7736.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question is a bit difficult to understand; could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: "The line before" is not a concept an RDBMS is aware of. Show your DDL and example data.

Answer (score 0):

The self-join will work for this purpose.  The idea is to look for the ticket with a product.  The discount lines will join where the ticket numbers match and the discount line doesn't contain a product and the product line number plus one equals the discount line number.

```
   select p.ticket,
          p.line,
          p.units,
          p.price as unit_price,
          ifnull(d.discount,0) as discount,
          p.units * (p.price - ifnull(d.discount,0)) as sale_price
     from ticketlines p
left join ticketlines d on (d.ticket=p.ticket and d.line=p.line+1 and d.product is null)
    where p.product is not null;
```